# How can I replace a DOM node and wrap it after?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replacewith

I have a div which I'm replacing with a textarea like:

```
var $targetDiv = $('#the-div');
var $newDiv = $('#the-new-div');

$targetDiv.replaceWith($newDiv);
```

Which would turn:

```
<div id="the-div"></div>
```

into:

```
<div id="the-new-div"></div>
```

How would I wrap `<div id="the-new-div"></div>` in a div called `<div id="the-new-div-wrapper">`?

So the outcome would become:

```
<div id="the-new-div-wrapper">
<div id="the-new-div">
</div>
</div>
```

```
$targetDiv.replaceWith($newDiv).wrap('<div id="the-new-div-wrapper"' />')
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I believe the single quotes are not matching in the wrapping html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the wrapping first

```
$targetDiv.wrap('<div id="the-new-div-wrapper" />').replaceWith($newDiv);
```

Or make it in two lines:

```
$targetDiv.replaceWith($newDiv);
$newDiv.wrap('<div id="the-new-div-wrapper" />');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VcPQG/)

There's also a typo in your code: `$targetDiv.replaceWith($newDiv).wrap('<div id="the-new-div-wrapper"' />')` There is an additional apostrophe, which shouldn't be there.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried it that way originally. Oh well. You clever man, you. Thanks! I'll accept when the limit is up.

Comment: The problem is that the replaceWith seems to return the old div, not the new one. So chaining the wrap after the replace with, actually wraps the old div that doesn't exist anymore

Comment: @Stijn_d thanks for the explanation! :) Chain of events totally makes sense now that I think of it...

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$targetDiv.replaceWith($newDiv.wrap('<div id="the-new-div-wrapper"' />'));
```

it would actually wrap the div before the lot replace the target div but will achieve the same result.

See here

http://jsfiddle.net/WgW6Y/